# Highlight current page link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problem to highlight the active menu item in sidebar using Javascript. So I called setPage() in the  to highlight current menu item, but nothing happens. Any ideas to solve it?

Btw, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="nav.html">Main page </a>
    <a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="page2.html">Dummy page 2</a>
    <a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="page3.html">Dummy page 3</a>
    <a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="page4.html">Dummy page 4</a>
    <script language="text/javascript">setPage()</script>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background:#CCC;
    font:140% "Times New Roman", Times, serif, Arial;
    line-height:1.5;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.sidebar-nav-item {
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.sidebar-nav-item.active,
a.sidebar-nav-item:hover,
a.sidebar-nav-item:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function extractPageName(hrefString) { // This function is 
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return (arr.length < 2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length - 2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length - 1].toLowerCase();
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage) {
            arr[i].className = "sidebar-nav-item active";
        }
    }
}

function setPage() {
    if (hrefString = document.location.href)
        hrefString = document.location.href;
    else
        hrefString = document.location;

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-nav") != null)
        setActiveMenu(document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-nav-item"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: go with the css attribute :active ...

Comment: :active is only active in the second ur mouse is down.

Comment: Why do you want to use Pure JS? Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: Not sure :active is going to work, I believe the OP wants the link to change color (or something similar) when you're on that specific page, not just clicking on it.

Comment: `if (hrefString = document.location.href)` sets global variable `hrefString` to be equal to page hash. Use == or beter ===

Answer (score 1):

It's not `language`, but `type`, that's your first mistake (although it might work, it's not correct according to standards.

For setting link active state, get the according `anchor` (`<a>`) element and add class `active` to it. That should work as you've already defined style for active link, I think that should work as it is now.

Your have 2 problems in `setPage` function:

```
if (hrefString = document.location.href)
```

The `=` symbol means assignment of value, use `==` or `===` for comparison. I really recommend `===`, because it literally compares 2 objects, instead only the value, as is the case with `==` comparison.

Second is that `hrefString` is not defined before this if statement (at least not in code you've provided), so javascript will throw error and stop execution.